# nodejs integrated possibility of ajax call with nodejs

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am using node.js and my call is exactly after the `socket.emit()`.

My problem is that if the AJAX call fails but the socket interaction continues, the logic will fail.

Is there a possibility to send ajax call with socket?

Comment: Could you add some code and rephrase what you exactly want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you wait to get the response from the Ajax call and then call `socket.emit`.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/api/method",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() {
  socket.emit();
});
```

Comment: hie krasimir.. actually am doing auctions and biddings.If bidder is click on bid if it takes more time to reach the seller through responce,then there will be a problm.Viceversa for seller too.seller must accept biddings.

Comment: hie @Paul Mougel .http://www.liveauctioneers.com/ you can see this (click red color label with text Watch Live) then propt will open.it is flash am implementing it with jquery.